# How I can Use Crystal Report 8.0 in C# 2008?

Tags: c#

I want USe Crystal Report 8.0 (Native Version) in My .Net Apllication?
how i can use this in .net.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Google](http://www.google.com.br/search?q=Crystal+Report+8.0+in+C%23) is your friend:

- [Crystal Reports in ASP.NET](http://www.beansoftware.com/ASP.NET-Tutorials/Using-Crystal-Reports.aspx)
- [Reporting XML data using Crystal Reports and Windows Forms](http://dotnetslackers.com/articles/xml/ReportingXMLDataUsingCrystalReportsAndWindowsForms.aspx)
- [Crystal Reports in Winforms Windows Forms with Parameters C#.NET](http://csharpdotnetfreak.blogspot.com/2009/07/crystal-reports-in-winforms-parameter.html)